# CFNetwork crash using swift in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, nsoperationqueue, cfnetwork

I have the following crash in my application but I cannot reproduce it to find its source. The main work is multiple asynchronous network **upload** requests, which are placed in a **concurrent** OperationQueue and support **background** transition too.

Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x174037ae0 :: NSOperation 0x17044f7b0 (QOS: DEFAULT)
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000ce6fabec8

Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x170036660 :: NSOperation 0x17425e360 (QOS: DEFAULT)

```
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x181c21704 objc_object::release() + 8
1  CFNetwork                      0x1839a196c __destroy_helper_block_.465 + 40
2  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x1820afa28 _Block_release + 144
3  Foundation                     0x183c0623c -[NSBlockOperation dealloc] + 64
4  Foundation                     0x183cc245c __NSOQSchedule_f + 484
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x18205a1bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1820683dc _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x18205d9a4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x18206a34c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x18206a0ac _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1822632a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182262d8c start_wqthread + 4
```

The app is written in **Swift 3**. Is there anything you can propose?

Comment: Can you show us the coding lines where you are getting this crash?

Comment: In debug mode I cannot get this crash because I cannot reproduce it. I get this report from Fabric (which does not include coding lines for the crash) and I was hoping to get some help in order to start looking at a certain place.

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved this exact same crash log by updating a 3rd party library. The issue in that library was defining a block object as (strong, nonatomic) instead of (copy). It was an Objective-C library, but the same strong/weak principles would apply with Swift block object properties. If those blocks were added to an NSOperationQueue, you could see that error. Do you have any strong block properties or any strong references in NSOperationQueues?

Comment: I have strong references (not blocks) in the Operation but I make sure that I do not access them after I cancel or finish the Operation. My problem is that  the guy that previously implemented had sort of 2 delegates for the same operation. When he created the the URLSession he set self as delegate (the operation itself) and if the session was continued in the background, he added the completionHandler of handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession to another custom delegate. So maybe the two delegates sometimes run together and there was a conflict. I now did it with 1 custom delegate and I wait...